# PHP Date (day) changes before midnight

Tags: php

I changed

```
<?php echo date('l, F, jS, Y); ?>
```

to

```
<?php 
        date_default_timezone_set('Denver');
        echo date('l, F, jS, Y'); ?>
```

I am in the mountain time-zone and wanted that as the default. Any ideas?

Comment: You sure that's a valid timezone - should probably be `America/Denver`

Comment: But besides the bad timezone (see : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) that you've used, what do you want to achieve? What's your question? You want to change the default server timezone? Or..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@CD001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886824/cd001) mentions in his comments, your timezone used is faulty (change to `America/Denver`). Instead of using `date_default_timezone_set` you can also set it runtime with `init_set()` or preset the default on the `php.ini` file.

**Set default timezone on runtime**

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Denver');
```

---

Or change default at configuration level

**Change `php.ini`**

Open the `php.ini` under `/etc/php.ini`.

Set the `date.timezone` to `America/Denver`

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Denver
```

**Restart server**

Restart the Apache to take the changes into account

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

**Check**

If you want to check if the settings have been saved correctly, do a `phpinfo();` and search for the field `Default timezone`.

Comment: You can also use `ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Denver');` inline

Comment: Yes true! I normally don't use inline's , but i've updated my answer since it's absolutely a possibility! Thanks for remarking :)

Comment: I normally use a `php_value` flag in the relevant Apache `<VirtualHost>` directive; set the timezone per website then... unless I'm using a shared hosting system, then it's `ini_set()` ;)